# assert interface{} to int64

Tags: go, go-gin

i am using gin, i use `c.shouldBind` to bind the data to the struct, the use `c.set` to set the params in the context. when i use `c.getInt64` to get the params, it can't return the value i set in the context(i set a 1), it return a zero. it failed to assert a float64 1 to a int64 0.

i have google it but can't get the answer i want

here are my debug code

```golang
// GetInt64 returns the value associated with the key as an integer.
func (c *Context) GetInt64(key string) (i64 int64) {
    if val, ok := c.Get(key); ok && val != nil {
        i64, _ = val.(int64)
    }
    return
}
```

the val is 1, but it returns 0

So can anybody tell me why and how to solve it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code *in the body of the question*, not at an external link.

Answer (score 1):

Golang can't convert types implicitly. You can use the `GetFloat64` method.

Answer (score 0):

It depends the value which you really set in, and check the key is right, After that, Maybe you could use assertion after `Get` like: `value := c.Get("From_validator_page").(Int64)`